# html & css not moving my item into correct position

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I am doing this on a Joomla website inside a JUMI link in a php file

with that said - it seems like simple html / css and I assume I am just doing something wrong -

perhaps its more in depth and is because the Joomla Article / Module is overriding my css?

PHP/HTML File:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_scripts/css/login.css" type="text/css">
<body>
    <p class="logform">
    <form action="http://www.link.com" method="post">
        username: <input type="username" name="username"><br>
        password: <input type="password" name="passw"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
.logform {
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
   right:5px;
}
```

Comment: or, because, there is no element with class nor id logform

Comment: the head is part of joomla
the class i mistyped when putting it on the stack, sorry the class is logform (i fixed the question to reflect)

Comment: @user3424754 I thought this, but now I think it's most probably because it's wrong to wrap forms into paragraphs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to wrap a form into a paragraph `<p>` which is kinda invalid.

This should be wrapped into a `div` element.

```
<div class="logform">
    <form action="http://www.link.com" method="post">
        username: <input type="username" name="username"><br>
        password: <input type="password" name="passw"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```